# Second Curl request on page never executed

Tags: php, curl, eventbrite

I'm running a page to collect the events a logged in user has created through the Eventbrite API.

the first CURL request returns a response fine and echoing the org_id gives the correct response, however for the second curl request both response and err are empty and there are no errors in error_log, I ran the request on its own in postman and the correct response was returned.

(session_init.php just contains `<?php session_start()?>`)

```
<?php
include 'session_init.php';

$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => "https://www.eventbriteapi.com/v3/users/me/organizations/",
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "GET",
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    "Authorization: Bearer ".$_SESSION['token'],
  ),
));
$response = curl_exec($curl);
$err = curl_error($curl);

curl_close($curl);
echo $response;
//echo $response.organizations.id;
$response=(json_decode($response, true));
//print_r($response);
$org_id = $response['organizations'][0]['id'];
echo $org_id;
if(ISSET($org_id)){
$_SESSION['org_id'] = $org_id;
}
else{
  $_SESSION['org_id']=null;
}
$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => "https://www.eventbriteapi.com/v3/organizations/".$_SESSION['org_id']."/events",
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "GET",
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    "Authorization: Bearer ".$_SESSION['token'],
  ),
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);
$err = curl_error($curl);

curl_close($curl);

if ($err) {
  echo "cURL Error #:" . $err;
} else {
  echo $response;
  $response=(json_decode($response, true));
}

 ?>
```

EDIT: this is the result of `$info = curl_getinfo($curl); var_dump($info);`

```
array(26) { ["url"]=> string(66) "https://www.eventbriteapi.com/v3/organizations/299067012672/events" ["content_type"]=> string(24) "text/html; charset=utf-8" ["http_code"]=> int(301) ["header_size"]=> int(1520) ["request_size"]=> int(176) ["filetime"]=> int(-1) ["ssl_verify_result"]=> int(0) ["redirect_count"]=> int(0) ["total_time"]=> float(0.42656) ["namelookup_time"]=> float(2.5E-5) ["connect_time"]=> float(0.090498) ["pretransfer_time"]=> float(0.268933) ["size_upload"]=> float(0) ["size_download"]=> float(0) ["speed_download"]=> float(0) ["speed_upload"]=> float(0) ["download_content_length"]=> float(-1) ["upload_content_length"]=> float(-1) ["starttransfer_time"]=> float(0.426508) ["redirect_time"]=> float(0) ["redirect_url"]=> string(67) "https://www.eventbriteapi.com/v3/organizations/299067012672/events/" ["primary_ip"]=> string(12) "52.22.172.91" ["certinfo"]=> array(0) { } ["primary_port"]=> int(443) ["local_ip"]=> string(13) "46.37.183.253" ["local_port"]=> int(40102) }
```

Comment: Have you checked the server error logs for any errors? `$response[organizations][0][id];` would throw a warning because the keys should be quoted. `$response['organizations'][0]['id'];`. You can also try echoing your url to verify that the Url looks correct.

Comment: "and there are no errors in error_log," yep, nothing in error_log for the server, echoing the url comes out as https://www.eventbriteapi.com/v3/organizations/299067012672/events which is what i used in postman.

Comment: added the speachmarks, same result

Comment: Where you have assigned the token to $_SESSION['token'] ?

Comment: How about adding `$info = curl_getinfo($curl); var_dump($info);` to that second request to get some details about what is going on.

Comment: You can access the array element with an index by using single or double quotes...how can you use $response[organizations][0][id]?

Comment: @BA_Webimax added to the end of the post (i put the command just before the 2nd curl_close)

Comment: @ChipParade Looks like your request is getting redirected `http_code = 301`. You should add a trailing slash to the URL. Change this `"https://www.eventbriteapi.com/v3/organizations/".$_SESSION['org_id']."/events"` to `"https://www.eventbriteapi.com/v3/organizations/".$_SESSION['org_id']."/events/"`

Comment: @BA_Webimax that fixed it, thanks, you saved me a good few hours more frustration